# Update a variable

Tags: flutter, dart, var, flutter-web

I am currently stuck on a problem in flutter, where I have a variable that is used to display a certain value. **Later** in the same code **I update the value** but the Textfield that displays the old value **doesn't show the new value**. Is there any way to Stream this kind of variable into a Textfield. Thanks in advance!
The variable contains a **DateTime value** and is **converted into a String**.

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Text(enteredDate.toString()),
onPressed: () {
...
});
```

Comment: add a code where you are changing enteredDate. you have to call setState as value change.

Comment: Are you using a Stateful Widget and are you invoking the setState() method?

Comment: Please include the full code that is relevant to this value you speak of. Showing where you are displaying the value is not enough, we need to see how you are attempting to update it.